# Reading in different numbers of parameters in C

Tags: c, parameters, logic, scanf

The input would look something like this:

```
AND 1 0 2
OR 3 1 4
XOR 5 1 3
ENEE140 10 7 8 9
NOT 6 11
```

where the first parameter in each line is a logic operator and the numbers that follow are gates. I was wondering what the best way of reading in these parameters are, since I can't just `scanf("%s %d %d %d")` because some operators (ENEE140) have more than 3 integer parameters (it has 4).

Comment: Read the whole line as string, then read the opcode and the operands out of it (it's a simple case of parsing).

Comment: look at `strtok*` functions to split strings.

Comment: you could have a `switch case` based on the first character and 3 different `scanf` calls scanning for 2 or 3 or 4 numbers

Comment: Thanks guys. I forgot to mention that our professor won't let us use anything inside the string.h library because it's an intro class and he doesn't want any of us having any "advantages." the switch case sounds viable though, so I will try that out. Thanks so much!

Comment: You should still use the string parsing method. Writing those string operations is an excellent was to learn about programming.

Comment: agree with @johnelemans: writing a "kind of" `strtok` is not complicated and splitting text lines is a useful thing.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the spaces with null. Then these can be thought of as separate strings.
Something like (assume input line is called char * input):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
        char input[1000];
        printf("Enter line, or press return when finished\n");
        for(;;)
        {
            fgets(input, 999, stdin);
            if (*input == '\n')
                break;
            char *begin = input;
            char *end = input;
            // remember string begin and end points
            while (*end) ++end;
            // replace spaces with null
            for (;*begin;++begin) {
                if (*begin == ' ')  {
                    *begin = 0; 
                }
            }
            // Now parse each string

            for (begin = input; begin < end; ++begin) {
                if (begin == input)  {
                    printf("Command: %s\n", begin);
                } else {
                    int value = atoi(begin);
                    printf("Value: %d\n", value);
                }
                while (*begin)  {
                    ++begin; // skip to null
                }
            }        
        }
    }
```